# Spring Cloud Data Flow Stream resource reading from application.yaml

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have created my own stream source, processor, sink. When i deploy the apps and create a stream the properties are not being read from the application.yaml file which is present on the resource folder.

I have tried both the below way on applicaiton.yaml file.
app:
 app-name:
   properties

and without app: app-name as well.

Comment: It depends on the properties. SCDF sets binding related properties which will override the same properties in the application classpath. Any properties that are not overridden will be applied as expected.

Comment: @dturanski can you help me in solving the issue. source, porcessor, sink is unable to read properties from applicaiton.yaml when i deploy and app start fails

Comment: It could be a lot of things. Can you share your code?

Comment: its simple code i am following https://github.com/altfatterz/spring-cloud-dataflow-streaming-example and these configurations are not being picked from application yaml

Comment: HI @dturanski can you help me on this